# directives communication when many instances of parent directive are present

Tags: angularjs-directive

Can parent-child directive communication using 'require' be used if there are multiple instances of both parent and child directives? (i.e. both directives are inside ng-repeat blocks)

I have a parent child directive relationship, but the parent directive is included in an ng-repeat block. When I use 'require' on the child directive it always binds to the first instance of the parent directive and not the first one above the child directive in the DOM.

Comment: Yeah it works; we are doing that with angular-gridster

Comment: Thanks Cory, I looked at angular-gridster. I can see gridsterItem can be repeated within one gridster, but can you put a grister in an ng-repeat as well and still gridsterItem(s) bind to their respective gridstr? If so could you please show me an example. I really have been trying to get this working for 3 days now. I appreciate any help. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible; as nice visual example (I'm a visual person) [angular-gridster](https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster) has parent and children directives.  If we just throw them in a `ng-repeat` everything works.  This is because ng-repeat has its own scope in which it creates  new child scopes for each item.

[See this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0tKfzFGoECJjtraIsOBA?p=preview)